# If Console class derived from object why i cant use object method on it?

Tags: c#, object, console-application

I Read this (from MSDN):

Inheritance Hierarchy

System.Object

System.Console

But i get an error while trying to write:

Console.Tostring();
why?

If its derived from object it should contain object method no?

Answer (score 1):

Actually `Console` is a static class (as you can see on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.console(v=vs.110).aspx)) and `ToString()` is an instance method. You can only invoke it from an instance of an Object, but you can't create instances of static classes.